# Need help on alfresco CMIS APIs

Tags: api, categories, alfresco, taxonomy, cmis

Need help on alfresco CMIS APIs.

Need CMIS apis for  *uploading file*  and *creating folder*.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Those are fairly basic CMIS operations, how far did you get with using an existing CMIS client to perform those operations?

Comment: I am using 
   http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/-default- /public/cmis/versions/1.0/atom/children?id=b0697dd1-ae94-4bf6-81c8-5e2fa098ddfa  and kept it in form action to upload a file. But getting getting an error " HTTP Status 400 - invalidArgument

Properties must be set!"

Comment: That's a CMIS URL, yes. How are you trying to talk to it? With a CMIS library? With straight restful HTTP calls? (not recommended for beginners!) What tutorials have you tried following? What code have you written so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this link :

http://chemistry.apache.org/

Apache chemistry has client APIs for many languages. You have not mentioned anything related to which language you want to use. You can choose your language and download the library for that. It has documentation related to all the usages. Go through them and you should be able to use them.

Comment: I am using PHP language.

Comment: PHP libraries are available there... have a look at them

Comment: I am using below form to upload a document. But form action is missing in the tutorial. http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/pra/1/concepts/cmis-1.1-browser-binding-post.html   Also I am using http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.0/atom/children?id=b0697dd1-ae94-4bf6-81c8-5e2fa098ddfa in form action and getting "Property not set" error.  please help me.